# Magento 1.9 - Translate text in php file

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, inline-translations

How I can translate this text in a php file, I want to translate $message

```
  if (!$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
            if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                $notifysymbol = "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."/noticeicons/1489953827_warning.png' >";
                $message = $this->__('<div class="notit"><span class="notification-symbol">%s</span><div class="rowt2"> <span class="added_cart">Product added to cart</span><br/><span class="small-text"> Go to the checkout to complete your purchase or add more products</span></div></div>',$notifysymbol);
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
            }
            $this->_goBack();
        }
```

[image]

and this is the text in the Custom field:

```
<div class="notit"><span class="notification-symbol">%s</span><div class="rowt2"> <span class="added_cart">Product added to cart</span><br/><span class="small-text"> Go to the checkout to complete your purchase or add more products</span></div></div>
```

The text is the core_translate table too

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$message` is already translatable, because you use `$this->__()` to generate it. So, you can enable [Inline Translation](http://inchoo.net/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/) to translate it.

However, it is not best practise to use HTML code inside a translatable string. Imagine you string will some time be changed by your client - this will surely result in errors when HTML code needs to be changed. I would suggest the following solution:

```
<?php
    $headline = $this->__('Product added to cart');
    $text = $this->__('Go to the checkout to complete your purchase or add more products');
    $message = $this->__('<div class="notit"><span class="notification-symbol">%s</span><div class="rowt2"> <span class="added_cart">%s</span><br/><span class="small-text">%s</span></div></div>', $notifysymbol, $headline, $text);
```

Comment: Hi I use Inline Translations but I can't see any modifications after press on Submit and clear and refresh the cache. I edit my post I add my translation window for this text.

Comment: Can you check the `core_translate` table in the database if your edit is there?

Comment: yes is there I put an image into my post to see it there

Comment: The strange thing is this: the translation is for the Excellence_Ajax module, and the php code is in the app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php file

Comment: Ok, first of all - please don't edit core files. ;) This will make patches and updates impossible. You can write your own modules for anything, or at least copy the file+path to `app/code/local`. Second, have you tried changing the prefix for `string` in the database to `Mage_Checkout`?

Comment: belive me I know very well the part with core files ;) I change the string right now, but in the Inline Translation is same old Excellence_Ajax

Comment: Can you use `Mage::helper('checkout')->__()` for the translations, and change in the database "Excellence_Ajax::<..." to "Mage_Checkout::<..."?

Comment: I insert your code and is work now. thank you so much I really appreciate your help.

Comment: no problem, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

I found the same question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28226922/3150195). Try this out:

*One argument, in one place:*

```
Mage::helper('module')->__('Hi %s, there is an error', $name);
```

*Two arguments, in two places:*

```
Mage::helper('module')->__('Hi %s, there is an error with code %s', $name, $code);
```

*One argument, in two places:*

```
Mage::helper('module')->__('Hi %1$s, there is an error. Your name is %1$s', $name);
```

*Two arguments, swapping places:*

```
// Template or block file
Mage::helper('module')->__('Hi %1$s %2$s, there is an error', $firstname, $lastname);

// CSV translation
"Hi %1$s %2$s, there is an error", "%2$s, %1$s received an error"
```

Comment: thank you but how will look this on my code?